# ForEach in ForEach, fetching Data

Tags: swiftui, foreach, swift-data

I'm building a View right now, where I try to get several DisclosureGroup with ForEach based on categories. This was the easy part. My problem is the second Array, where I want to fetch items with said category.

I am new to the game and still learning, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Code here:

```
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query private var category: [CategoryModel]
    @Query private var bonsai: [BonsaiModel]
    
    @State private var searchQuery = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                List {
                    Section {
                        // Query category to build DisclosureGroup
                        ForEach(category) { categories in // Loop through category
                            DisclosureGroup(categories.name) {
                                
                                ForEach(bonsai) { items in // Loop through bonsai, where bonsai.category = category
                                    Text(items.name)
                                        .bold()
                                    if let category = items.category {
                                        Text(category.name) // show category.title
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray))
                                            .bold()
                                            
                                    } else {
                                        Text(" ")
                                            .padding(.top, 4)
                                    }
                                
                                
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.top, 8)
                .listStyle(.inset)
```

I have put two Text-Items in it, to see what data I try to fetch in the "bonsai" ForEach.

Here is a picture, to visualize what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Right now you see everything, but you can see the categories which should used as a "filter" and only show in their Group.

My guess is, that it will work with compactMap or filter, but I have no clue how I get it to work.

Model here:

```
@Model
final class BonsaiModel {
    var uuid: UUID
    var timestamp: Date
    var purchased: Date
    var price: Double
    var name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var age: String
    
    @Attribute(.externalStorage)
    var bonsaiImageData: Data?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \CategoryModel.bonsai)
    var category: CategoryModel?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \SpeciesModel.bonsai)
    var species: SpeciesModel?
    
    init(price: Double = 0.00,
         name: String = "",
         isFavorite: Bool = false,
         age: String = "",
         bonsaiImageData: Data? = nil
    ) {
        self.uuid = UUID()
        self.timestamp = Date()
        self.purchased = Date()
        self.price = price
        self.name = name
        self.isFavorite = isFavorite
        self.age = age
        self.bonsaiImageData = bonsaiImageData

    }
    

}

@Model
final class CategoryModel {
    @Attribute(.unique) var name: String = ""
    
    var bonsai: [BonsaiModel]?
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

    }
    
}

@Model
final class SpeciesModel {
    @Attribute(.unique) var name: String = ""
    
    var bonsai: [BonsaiModel]?
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How does CategoryModel and BonsaiModel relate to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your model you can directly access the relationship property for the BonsaiModel in CategoryModel, that way you only get the objects that belongs to the current CategoryModel and do not need to perform any filtering or matching of objects.

```
ForEach(category) { categories in
    DisclosureGroup(categories.name) {
        ForEach(categories.bonsai ?? []) { items in
            Text(items.name)
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: I would suggest making the to-many side of the relationship none-optional

```
var bonsai: [BonsaiModel] = []
```

also with this solution you can remove the query for BonsaiModel from your view

Comment: Obviously, works as well. :) I must confess, this is better to read and to adapt. I was able to write another section, where I fetch items with no categories on my own. But I have relied on the BonsaiModel to fetch all items without category. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a filter in your inner loop like this:

```swift
ForEach(category) { categories in // Loop through category
    ForEach(bonsai.filter { $0.category == category } )
```

There are many Sequence functions similar to `filter` that you can learn about in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence).

Since you're new to this, I'll also say that if you're confused by that syntax, read up on [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures) and in particular the section on [Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures#Trailing-Closures).

Comment: Thanks @CuriousJorge ! It works with category == categories. But yes, I need to reed up on Trailing Closures. Thanks for this tip as well.

Comment: @DennisHH This isn't a very efficient solution, at least not if you have set up a proper relationship between your models.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i have updated my post above and posted my Model. Until now, I thought my model would be alright? at least everything is working. Can you tell me, what would be the efficient solution?

Comment: @DennisHH See my separate answer